# How to inject/handle usage of HttpContex.Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure, autofac, azure-caching

I have a legacy application that is extensively using `HttpContext.Cache`...
This application is now suppose to move to **Windows Azure (multi-role)**.
It will of course cause problems with cache going out of sync on different roles.
I was thinking about *injecting* (I'm using Autofac) my "AzureCacheWrapper" (wrapper on `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache`) into `HttpContext.Cache` so legacy application continues working but uses Azure cache instead?
Normally we should implement something like `ICacheProvider` but unfortunately there are some 3rd party DLLs that are using cache that we don't have access to (and don't know when 3rd party library is using Http cache)
I don't think cache provider can be configured through web.config (like OutputCaching) so the only solution seems to me to somehow inject my implementation into Add/Insert/Get methods on Runtime Cache. 
Unfortunately because of .NET implementation of System.Web.Caching.Cache (sealed class) I don't think I can override `HttpContextBase` to return different cache or inject into `System.Web.Caching.Cache` itself...

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your application needs code/architectural change...

If you had your own class which handles getting and setting the cache, Which may easier now to change your code/architecture in one place.

If you are going to use Single role then no problem exist in your scinario. If possible you can run your webrole in ExtraLarge slot.